# Group click listener in android expandable list view

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an expandable list view where the first group is empty i.e. *it has no children while all others have children*. Now I have to implement `onChildClick` for all the groups *except* the first one.

For the first one the requirement is that *onClick* the group itself some action has to be taken.

So I implemented *onGroupClickListener* and put the condition

```
if(groupPosition == 0){ //action}
```

but this has disabled all the groups and now I am not able to see the children for any group.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
      if(mygroup.getChildCount()>0){
      //your action
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

put to your empty group, an empty array

and then add

```
 expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            switch (listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)) {
                case "YOUR_CLICKABLE GROUP":
                      //do something  
                      break;

            }
        }
    });
```